# Why my layout / css is screwed?

Tags: css

i can't manage to find where is the cause of the problem :

the page where the css is 'broken' : [messy layout](http://bit.ly/cGTLfi)

the same page, but with a another text in it shows the result as excepted : [good layout](http://bit.ly/bp6Bmb)

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a (small) stack of [machine detectable errors.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seek-team.com%2Fen%2Fplayers%2Fcounter-strike-source%2Fjango%2Fmiddle%2F1&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) It isn't worth doing any further investigation until they are fixed.