# Why my layout is screwed ? (2)

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why my layout / css is screwed ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431051/why-my-layout-css-is-screwed)

Ok, fixing the error reported by W3C did not fixed the broken layout.

the page where the css is 'broken' : [messy layout](http://bit.ly/cGTLfi)

the same page, but with a another text in it shows the result as excepted : [good layout](http://bit.ly/bp6Bmb)

If with your lynx eye you spot the error, thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.logoteam` has a width of 20%.

the 20% is derived from the width of `.bloc-level`, its parent element.

- puls page has a width of 695 px. 20% of 695 = 139px
- jango has a width of 421 px. 20% of = 81px

So to work around this you can

- a) set a width of 695px on `.float1` so 20% of 695px is always 139px
- b) set a width on `span.logoteam` to be 139px

Answer (score 1):

Set a width on the span surrounding the the image.

```
<span class="floatl logoteam" style="width: 130px;">
                    <img height="100" width="100" class="border_white" alt="general.jpg" src="/uploads/logo_player/general.jpg">
                </span>
```

Comment: thanks it fixed a problem but now the description is way to small :O lol one problem fixed another appear :O

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the width of the "presentation" class you will be fine as well. It looks like the design establishes a fixed width for this regardless, so it might be a good thing to enforce it on the CSS. It'll let you align the centered "Do you want to know :" section with the "reveal this offer" button too.

Comment: thanks everything is fine now